# jQuery double slider handles overlapping

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to modify the jQuery double slider. Everything works fine except one thing. Then 2 handles are at the same position the one that was not active during the last move can't be dragged afterward, unless you move the other one on different position. Here is an example:

http://author.euro.confirmit.com/extwix/extquicktest_p564156043.aspx?__qtkey=9cffc015a10443a6ac0706c1abb41324&l=9

So if you try to move the lower handle first you can't or you will move the upper one.

My code is like below:

```
<div style='width: 510px; text-align: right; color: #000000; margin-top: 50px;'> 100 </div>
<div id='rail'> </div>
<div style='width: 500px; text-align: left; color: #000000; margin-bottom: 50px;'> 0 </div>

$( '#rail' ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      values: [ 50, 50 ],
      slide: function( event, ui ){  
          $('#upper_result').html(ui.values[0]); 
          $('#q160_1').val(ui.values[0]); 
          $('#lower_result').html(ui.values[1]); 
          $('#q160_2').val(ui.values[1]);
      }
 });

var lower = document.getElementById('rail').getElementsByTagName('a')[1];
var upper = document.getElementById('rail').getElementsByTagName('a')[0];

lower.style.cssText="left: 250px; top: 35px; background: url('http://media.jts-mr.com/CustomeQuestions/Classic Slider/lower_thumb.gif')";
lower.innerHTML = "<div class='result' id='lower_result' style='position: absolute; top: 22px;'>" + $( '#rail' ).slider( 'values', 1 ) + "</div>";
upper.innerHTML = "<div class='result' id='upper_result' style='position: absolute; top: -20px;'>" + $( '#rail' ).slider( 'values', 0 ) + "</div>";
```

How can I fix this bug?

Comment: Off topic: Why not `var lower = $('#rail a').eq(1)`?

Comment: I am used to work with JavaScript rather than jQuery. I didn't know that, but I will try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a jquery implementation choice rather than a bug.

If you really want to change this behavior, a fix could be to either:

- Check whether the user drags above or below the center line and change the top or bottom slider value accordingly.
- Check whether the drag direction is to the left or right side, then mark the top or bottom slider as the active one.

Comment: I am not very good at jQuery... could you please tell me how can I mark slider to become the active one? I tried to change z-Index of both thumbs but it didn't help.

Comment: I found a jQuery [bug report on this issue](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9553), I'd advice you to add a comment there if you're inexperienced with jQuery.
The selection is made in the _mouseCapture function of jquery.ui.slider.js, where you'd need to set `closestHandle` to the directed one if the event is a drag.